# Repositioning UIView causes oposite directions

Tags: ios, uiview

In the root view controller of my project, i wrote in the

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

I wrote:

```
self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x-50.0, self.view.center.y);
```

I expected that it will be move to the left direction, but actually it goes to right direction.

The same case for Y direction..

why this ?

thanks

EDITING

I tested that:
I presented this viewController modally, and I put the previews positioning code in the "viewDidAppear" part , then the coordinates seems reversed.
This is the code to presenting modal viewController:

```
ReadingViewController * readingController = [[ReadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReadingViewController" bundle:nil];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentModalViewController:readingController animated:NO];
```

I then commented this peace of code an added the View of this ViewController into the super view and not changed the positioning code inside "viewDidAppear" part , and i found it is working as I expected, i.e. moved to the left by 50 pixels.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Do you have any transforms (CGAffineTransform) on your views?

Comment: there were some CGAffineTransform, but i commented it and it is not working now!!

Comment: A CGAffineTransform will change the coord space of the view that is transformed.  If you transform a UIVIew with a Scale(-1,0) it will turn the X axis around meaning that if you then change the x position of a sub view it will move in the wrong direction.

Comment: Can you post all your viewDidAppear code.  Might help analyse it a bit more.

Comment: i added some explanation in the main question

Answer (score 1):

The code you have used is working perfectly with me.Check out once for the bindings.